# swift iOS - Not able to create array from tracker.frequency audiokit output

Tags: arrays, swift, audiokit

I am using AudioKit Microphone Analysis in my app to detect sound frequencies. Everything is working fine, however, I want to capture first few (may be 20 to 30) frequencies and store it in an array. I can print the frequencies using print(tracker.frequency). I am trying to use insert on an empty array to store the

Here's the code in my view controller

```
@objc func updateUI() {
    if tracker.amplitude > 0.01 {
        frequencyLbl.text = String(format: "%0.1f", tracker.frequency)

        var frequency = Float(tracker.frequency)


        while frequency > Float(noteFrequencies[noteFrequencies.count - 1]) {
            frequency /= 2.0

        }
        while frequency < Float(noteFrequencies[0]) {
            frequency *= 2.0
        }
        // This is not working. I need an array like [23.111, 234.555, 345.65.. etc]
        var dynamicFrequency: [Float] = [frequency]
        for f in dynamicFrequency {
           dynamicFrequency.insert(f, at: 0)
        }
        print(dynamicFrequency)


        var minDistance: Float = 10_000.0
        var index = 0

        for i in 0..<noteFrequencies.count {
            let distance = fabsf(Float(noteFrequencies[i]) - frequency)
            if distance < minDistance {
                index = i
                minDistance = distance
            }
        }
        let octave = Int(log2f(Float(tracker.frequency) / frequency))
        noteNameLbl.text = "\(noteNamesWithSharps[index])\(octave)"
        noteNameFlatsLbl.text = "\(noteNamesWithFlats[index])\(octave)"



    }
    amplitudeLbl.text = String(format: "%0.2f", tracker.amplitude)

}
```

The output shows are below

```
AKMicrophone.swift:init():45:Mixer inputs 8
Audio Kit Started
[27.1829815, 27.1829815]
[16.7672386, 16.7672386]
[32.2606049, 32.2606049]
[31.2773647, 31.2773647]
[31.2035122, 31.2035122]
[31.5194035, 31.5194035]
[32.4384956, 32.4384956]
[25.3139915, 25.3139915]
[28.1445961, 28.1445961]
```

However, I am expecting output as

```
    [27.1829815,16.7672386,32.2606049,31.2773647,31.2035122,31.5194035,32.43849 56,25.3139915,28.1445961]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `updateUI()` frequently. That's why `dynamicFrequency` is printed many times.
What you have to do to get the desired output is declare `dynamicFrequency` outside of `updateUI()` and print its contents once it has 20 frequencies or so:

```
var dynamicFrequency: [Float] = [frequency]
@objc func updateUI() {
    //...
    for f in dynamicFrequency {
        dynamicFrequency.insert(f, at: 0)
    }
    if dynamicFrequency.count == 20 {
        print(dynamicFrequency)
        //The following line would be optional 
        //if you'd like to empty the dynamicFrequency 
        //once you print its contents
        dynamicFrequency.removeAll()
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was the exact problem. It works great now.

Comment: Glad I could help